# SQL Server - loop through temp table and calculate multiple values to insert rows into second table

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, sql-insert

I have a temp table, #TEMP1, which pulls back the next treatment date for a patients and the total number of planned treatments in a given date range.  Within the temp table is a value which gives me the minimum number of days between each treatment.

What I need to do is take the next treatment date, determine how many planned treatments there are after the next treatment date and populate a second temp table, #TEMP2, with the planned dates.

For example, in #TEMP1, contains the following data:

```
patient    next_tx_dt  planned_tx_cnt   min_days_bt   start_range  end_range
PATIENT_1  2/15/2015   4                28            2/1/2015     6/1/2015
PATIENT_2  2/05/2015   9                12            2/1/2015     6/1/2015
PATIENT_3  5/17/2015   1                112           2/1/2015     6/1/2015
```

I would like to loop through #TEMP1 and for each row, calculate the dates of planned treatment.  So one row could be looped through once (PATIENT_3) or nine times (PATIENT_2) and each loop results in a new row in #TEMP2.

PATIENT_1 would have the following results in #TEMP2 after a successful loop:

```
pat_id      planned_tx_dt   planned_tx_cnt
PATIENT_1   2/15/2015       1
PATIENT_1   3/15/2015       2
PATIENT_1   4/12/2015       3
PATIENT_1   5/10/2015       4
```

PATIENT_2 would have 9 rows and PATIENT_3 would only have 1 row in #TEMP2.

Is it possible to do this in SQL Server 2008?  I have done very basic loops before using a row count but this technically isn't looping through a table so I'm not sure how to get this started or if it is even possible (I do not have a whole lot of experience writing advanced SQL code).

Comment: in your #TEMP2 sample dataset, how are you calculating `planned_tx_dt` from the data in #TEMP1?

Comment: In my example, I just manually calculated the date but I think for the query, it would have to involve setting #TEMP1.planned_tx_cnt up as a variable and then some sort of loop to calculate each row?  For example, SET @TX_CNT = #TEMP1.planned_tx_cnt.

Comment: SELECT @I = 1
SELECT @TX_CNT = #TEMP1.planned_tx_cnt
WHILE (@I <= @TX_CNT)
BEGIN
DATEADD(d, (#TEMP1.min_days_bt * @I), #TEMP1.next_tx_dt) 
    SELECT @I = @I + 1
END

Comment: That's doable, you could do it using a `LOOP`, `CURSOR` or even a `recursive CTE`. But what I am failing to understand, why is the date part of `planned_tx_dt` different for the subsequent months. how did you determine 2/15, 3/15, 4/12, 5/10 instead of 2/15,3/15,4/15,5/15?

Comment: This is where a numbers or tally table comes to use. There is no need for looping here at all.

Comment: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/

Comment: @SoulTrain - It can't be 2/15, 3/15, 4/15, 5/15 because there are different number of days in each month.  Some of the treatment is chemo so there is often very little leeway.  So 3/15/2015 is exactly 28 days from 2/15/2015 and 4/12/2015 is exactly 28 days from 3/15/2015, and so on.

Comment: @SeanLange - thank you for the link, I will read it and see if I can make that work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you read the link I posted. Meanwhile here is a functional example using the information you posted. I actually have that cteTally as a view in my system so I don't have to ever recreate it. You can adjust the cte portion as needed to ensure you have enough rows.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') is not null
    drop table #temp1

create table #temp1
(
    patient varchar(50)
    , next_tx_dt date
    , planned_tx_cnt int
    , min_days_bt int
    , start_range date
    , end_range date    
)

insert #temp1
select 'PATIENT_1', '2/15/2015', '4', '28', '2/1/2015', '6/1/2015' union all
select 'PATIENT_2', '2/05/2015', '9', '12', '2/1/2015', '6/1/2015' union all
select 'PATIENT_3', '5/17/2015', '1', '112', '2/1/2015', '6/1/2015';

WITH
    E1(N) AS (select 1 from (values (1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))dt(n)),
    E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
    E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
    cteTally(N) AS 
    (
        SELECT  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
    )

select *, DATEADD(DAY, (N - 1) * min_days_bt, next_tx_dt)
from #temp1 t1
join cteTally t on t.N <= t1.planned_tx_cnt
--where t1.patient = 'PATIENT_1'
```

Comment: Thank you, your example actually helps me understand the article a bit better - totally new territory for me!

Comment: If you read that article and understand what it says and then understand this code it will change the way you look at data. Glad my example helped.